# how to remove repeated axes labels in a Seaborn facetgrid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to remove the repeated axis x labels of 'time' except for the bottom four panels

what should I do?

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(df_va1, col = 'Subject', hue = 'Subject', palette = 'GnBu_d',
                   col_wrap = 4, height = 1.5, aspect= .9)
grid.map(plt.plot, 'TimePoint', 'values', marker = 'o')
grid.set(xticks = [0,3,6,12], yticks = [0, 0.5, 1], xlim = (-0.5,12.5),
        xlabel = 'time', ylabel = 'values')
grid.fig.tight_layout(w_pad=1)
```

Here is the current plot
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use

```py
grid.set_axis_labels("time", "values")
```

and remove your `xlabel` and `ylabel` options.